# Prototype Creation Pattern

Tags: java, cloneable

In java we have and interface cloneable What I want to understand is why abstract class implements that interface there is still no implementation of clone() method of interface in abstract class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In java we have and interface cloneable What I want to understand is
>   why abstract class implements that interface there is still no
>   implementation of clone() method of interface in abstract class ?

Object class provides default implementation for `Object`'s methods whose `clone()` method.

When you look `Object` class, you can see that `clone()` specifies a particular keyword in its signature : `native`.

```
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

The `native` keyword is applied to a method to indicate that it is implemented in `JNI`(Java Native Interface).  
 
So, the implementation exists somewhere (probably in a C function but not exclusively...)  but not directly  in the Java source code of the method.

Finally, you should consider the `Cloneable interface` as what it stands for :  a marker `interface`. If you want that you object to be cloneable, implement this and if you don't care, do nothing :

> A class implements the Cloneable interface to indicate to the
>   Object.clone() method that it is legal for that method to make a
>   field-for-field copy of instances of that class. Invoking Object's
>   clone method on an instance that does not implement the Cloneable
>   interface results in the exception CloneNotSupportedException being
>   thrown.

Now, if  default implementation of `clone()` method (shallow copy) doesn't match with how do you want to clone your object, feel free to override `clone()` in the class of this object.

Answer (score 0):

The interface Cloneable is just to mark that the class supports the clone method in Object.clone().

> A class implements the Cloneable interface to indicate to the Object.clone() method that it is legal for that method to make a field-for-field copy of instances of that class.

You dont have to implement this method, the Object.clone do this for you, in a native code:

```
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

Take a look at those links:
[Object class source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/Object.java#Object.clone%28%29) and
[Cloneable Interface docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html)

Despite that, if you have one abstract class in the hierachy level, you dont have to implement the Cloneable in children class:

```
abstract class Animal implements Cloneable {

protected String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}

class Dog extends Animal {

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
private int age;

@Override
public Dog clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return (Dog)super.clone();
}
```

The clone still supported for Java